# How to scroll to an element after expanding with slideToggle?

Tags: jquery, scrollto, slidetoggle

scrollTo is not scrolling to a div that expands past the bottom of the page... any suggestions? (jQuery 1.3, scrollTo 1.42)

```
function toggleCollapsible(ownerDiv) {
    ownerDiv.next(".Collapsible").slideToggle("fast", 
                                              $.scrollTo(ownerDiv, "slow"));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried your code and it works, but you forgot to specify, that `$.scrollTo` should be inside an **anonymous function** (callback after `slideToggle` finishes toggling) and it even scrolled to under bottom of page..

```
function toggleCollapsible(ownerDiv) {
    ownerDiv.next(".Collapsible").slideToggle("fast", function(){
        $.scrollTo(ownerDiv, "slow");
    });
}
toggleCollapsible($("#target"));
```